# Baudrate calculation

Tags: baud-rate

Think that a MC has an external clock 16MHz and uses internal prescaler @16.  It has a embedded code that enables serial at a boudrate of 9600.
What is the boudrate if external clock is changed to 8MHz and internal prescaler to 4.
Explain why.

Can anyone help me about this problem

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the uC code implementation. Guess the baudrate should be the same if your code works.